# TypeError:unsupported format string passed to function .__format__

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Working on jupyter notebooks, I came across this problem:

```
TypeError:unsupported format string passed to function .__format__
```

This is where the code starts:

```
def evaluate_preds(y_true, y_preds):
    """
    Performs Evaluation comp on y_true labels and y_preds labels on a classification
    """
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true,y_preds)
    precision = precision_score(y_true,y_preds)
    recall = recall_score(y_true,y_preds)
    f1 = f1_score(y_true,y_preds)
    metric_dict = {"accuracy": round(accuracy,2),
                  "precision": round(precision,2),
                  "recall": round(recall,2),
                  "f1": round(f1,2)}

    print(f"Accuracy :{ accuracy_score*100:.2f}%")
    print(f"Precision :{ precision_score:.2f}")
    print(f"Recall :{ recall_score:.2f}")
    print(f"F1 :{ f1_score:.2f}")

    return metric_dict
```

This below code is being run on a different cell in jupyter notebook

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

np.random.seed(42)

heart_disease_shuffled= heart_disease.sample(frac=1)

X= heart_disease_shuffled.drop("target",axis =1)
y = heart_disease_shuffled["target"]

train_split = round(0.7 * len(heart_disease_shuffled))
valid_split = round(train_split + 0.15 * len(heart_disease_shuffled))

X_train,y_train = X[:train_split], y[:train_split]
X_valid,y_valid = X[train_split:valid_split], y[train_split:valid_split]

X_test,y_test = X[valid_split:], y[:valid_split]

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)


# Make Baseline preds

y_preds = clf.predict(X_valid)

# Evaluate classifier on validation set

baseline_metrics = evaluate_preds(y_valid, y_preds) 
baseline_metrics
```

How can I resolve it?

Tried changing the parameters and a bunch of other things but all of them popped up some errors like the one listed above

Comment: There should have been a full traceback message showing the line where this code failed. If so, post it in the question as another code block.

Comment: Try ```print(type(x), x)``` for each of your print lines.

Comment: I haven't spotted exactly where this happens in your code, but basically you are trying to format a function object with a format specifier. Suppose i `def foo(): pass`. And then I try `f"my data {foo:.2f}"`. I'm trying to format function "foo" with a float specifier. And that doesn't make sense. As @jwal suggested, find the failing line then print the types of each of the formated parameters.

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print functions instead of the values they return. For instance, you assign

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true,y_preds)
```

but then try to format the function, not the result

```
f"Accuracy :{ accuracy_score*100:.2f}%"
```

Instead, you should use the calculated value

```
f"Accuracy :{ accuracy*100:.2f}%"
```

But you've also created a dictionary with rounded values. You could use that dictionary with an f-string or use the `.format` method instead

```
f"Accuracy :{ metric_dict['accuracy']:.2f}"
# -- or --
"Accuracy : {accuracy:.2f}".format(**metric_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney for your kind feedback Changed it to the actual accuracy , precision and got my answer Btw the reason i was using accuracy_score was that the instructor used the same things and got the result but changed these parameters after sometime and I skipped through it & I was just copying him after I got error in my own code cuz I've just started learning Machine Learning 
Really sorry for all the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated/ working version,

```
import pandas as pd

def evaluate_preds(y_true, y_preds):
    """
    Performs Evaluation comp on y_true labels and y_preds labels on a classification
    """
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true,y_preds)
    precision = precision_score(y_true,y_preds)
    recall = recall_score(y_true,y_preds)
    f1 = f1_score(y_true,y_preds)
    metric_dict = {"accuracy": round(accuracy,2),
                      "precision": round(precision,2),
                      "recall": round(recall,2),
                      "f1": round(f1,2)}
    
    print(f"Accuracy :{ accuracy *100:.2f}%")
    print(f"Precision :{ precision:.2f}")
    print(f"Recall :{ recall:.2f}")
    print(f"F1 :{ f1:.2f}")
    return metric_dict
```

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

np.random.seed(42)

heart_disease_shuffled= heart_disease.sample(frac=1)

X= heart_disease_shuffled.drop("target",axis =1)
y = heart_disease_shuffled["target"]

train_split = round(0.7 * len(heart_disease_shuffled))
valid_split = round(train_split + 0.15 * len(heart_disease_shuffled))

X_train,y_train = X[:train_split], y[:train_split]
X_valid,y_valid = X[train_split:valid_split], y[train_split:valid_split]

X_test,y_test = X[valid_split:], y[:valid_split]

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Make Baseline preds
y_preds = clf.predict(X_valid)
# Evaluate classifier on validation set
baseline_metrics = evaluate_preds(y_valid, y_preds) 
baseline_metrics
```

Comment: As posted, this does not work. Indentation matters. Please clarify what you've changed

Comment: The indentation in the 1st code is correct I've just changed the thing accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score to the actual accuracy, precision, as posted by someone in the print statements in between the {} brackets

Comment: I've fixed the indentation for you. Please [edit] if not correct.

Comment: Thanks mate, I couldn't correct the indentation cuz when I copied and pasted the same as posted above I got the result in my Jupyter Notebook, So I thought the indentation is correct. 
Really appreciate your helping hand and cooperation :)